# PySpark: Using Object in RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently learning Python and want to apply it on/with Spark.
I have this very simple (and useless) script:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.v = str(value)

    def addValue(self, value):
        self.v += str(value)

    def getValue(self):
        return self.v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 1:
        print("Usage CC")
        exit(-1)

    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 1, 4]
    sc = SparkContext(appName="WordCount")
    d = sc.parallelize(data)
    inClass = d.map(lambda input: (input, MyClass(input)))
    reduzed = inClass.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a.addValue(b.getValue))
    print(reduzed.collect())
```

When executing it with

> spark-submit CustomClass.py

..the following error is thorwn (output shortened):

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 133, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1728, in add_shuffle_key
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 415, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
PicklingError: Can't pickle __main__.MyClass: attribute lookup __main__.MyClass failed
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)...
```

To me the statement

> `PicklingError: Can't pickle __main__.MyClass: attribute lookup __main__.MyClass failed`

seems to be important. It means that the class instances can't be serialized, right?
Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

- If you put `MyClass` in a separate file it can be pickled.  This is a common problem for many Python uses of pickle.  This is simple to solve by moving `MyClass` and the using `from myclass import MyClass`. Normally `dill` can fix these issues (as in `import dill as pickle`), but it didn't work for me here.
- Once this is solved, your reduce doesn't work since calling `addValue` return `None` (no return), not an instance of `MyClass`.  You need to change `addValue` to return `self`.
- Finally, the `lambda` need to call `getValue`, so should have `a.addValue(b.getValue())`

Together: 
`myclass.py`

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.v = str(value)

    def addValue(self, value):
        self.v += str(value)
        return self

    def getValue(self):
        return self.v
```

`main.py`

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from myclass import MyClass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 1:
        print("Usage CC")
        exit(-1)

    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 1, 4]
    sc = SparkContext(appName="WordCount")
    d = sc.parallelize(data)
    inClass = d.map(lambda input: (input, MyClass(input)))
    reduzed = inClass.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a.addValue(b.getValue()))
    print(reduzed.collect())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it solved my problem! Maybe one additional question: is it advisable (e.g. performance wise) to use classes/objects or is it better to use tuples and primitives? Thanks!

Comment: Primitive types should give better performance since Java objects need to be converted to python objects to execute python functions (e.g., `lambda`s) which is easy for primitive types but requires additional serialization for classes.

Comment: Hi @KevinS just for curiosity: I am in a similar situation with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042241/broadcast-a-user-defined-class-in-spark I'll try to use dill. In alternative, shall I change the serialization mechanism?

Comment: Hi @KevinS just for curiosity: I am in a similar situation with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042241/broadcast-a-user-defined-class-in-spark I'll try to use dill. In alternative, shall I change the serialization mechanism?