# Broadcast a user defined class in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to broadcast a user defined variable in a PySpark application but I always have the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/home/.../sparkbroad.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    output = input_.map(lambda item: b.value.map(item))
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 97, in load
    return pickle.load(f)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FooMap'
```

The code, in the module `sparkbrad.py` is the following:

```
import random
import pyspark as spark

class FooMap(object):

    def __init__(self):
        keys = list(range(10))
        values = [2 * key for key in keys]
        self._map = dict(zip(keys, values))

    def map(self, value):
        if value not in self._map:
            return -1
        return self._map[value]


class FooMapJob(object):

    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self._inputs = inputs
        self._foomap = FooMap()

    def run(self):
        sc = spark.SparkContext('local', 'FooMap')
        input_ = sc.parallelize(self._inputs, 4)
        b = sc.broadcast(self._foomap)
        output = input_.map(lambda item: b.value.map(item))
        b.unpersist()
        result = list(output.toLocalIterator())
        sc.stop()
        return result


def main():
    inputs = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]
    job = FooMapJob(inputs)
    print(job.run())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I am running it via the:

```
:~$ spark-submit --master local[4] --py-files sparkbroad.py sparkbroad.py
```

where I have added the `--py-files` argument but it looks it doesn't change that much. Unfortunately, I could not find any example online dealing with broadcasting of complex classes (just lists or dictionaries). Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: placing the `FooMap` class in a separate module, everything seems working fine, even without the `--py-files` directive.

Comment: Can you try to add the .py file in the code itself: `sc.addFile('sparkbroad.py')` instead of `--py-files` flag?

Comment: @dzejdzej thanks for the tip. I have done that but nothing changed.

Comment: You can try to separate the part of the program which initiates context and loads data from the logic using two files. This will make it easier to debug the import issue.

Comment: @dzejdzej I tried and apparently everything works fine now... but still can't get *why*. Anyway, I updated the original question.

Comment: I found it helpful as well. Thanks.Please add the updated text as an answer and mark it as the right answer so it's easier to find.

Comment: @MariusStănescu done, thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Placing the `FooMap` class in a separate module, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you add more detail about the solution? What do you do to make it a separate module?

Comment: @LouisYang make another file: `foo_map.py` with contents: `class FooMap(object)` etc. Then in the file that calls spark, `from .foo_map import FooMap`

Answer (score 4):

This is an addition to the previous answer.

You should import `FooMap` from another file not just define it in current file

maybe like this:
in foo_map.py:

```py
class FooMap(object):

    def __init__(self):
        keys = list(range(10))
        values = [2 * key for key in keys]
        self._map = dict(zip(keys, values))

    def map(self, value):
        if value not in self._map:
            return -1
        return self._map[value]
```

then in sparkbrad.py

```py
from foo_map import FooMap
class FooMapJob(object):

    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self._inputs = inputs
        self._foomap = FooMap()

    def run(self):
        sc = spark.SparkContext('local', 'FooMap')
        input_ = sc.parallelize(self._inputs, 4)
        b = sc.broadcast(self._foomap)
        output = input_.map(lambda item: b.value.map(item))
        b.unpersist()
        result = list(output.toLocalIterator())
        sc.stop()
        return result


def main():
    inputs = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]
    job = FooMapJob(inputs)
    print(job.run())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```